# How to show nested elements using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on creating dynamic elements, when User clicks on `add` I am creating another set of elements.

once I am creating the elements I have one select option there so on selection of particular options I am creating one more field.

I have `first name` and `select age` two elements, there I have age as `>18` and `<=18` so on this basis I am creating one more field.

Here when I am creating one more field I am facing issue.

**What I am doing**

- I am looping my elements
- then for new element which I going to be created on selection I am doing conditional rendering

  {onChangeAge && indexVal === index && (

So What I am doing is when onChange of select I am checking the value if it is >18 then setting state to that value and showing the new input field,

- But it is not working as expected, When I am selecting `>18` in first set of element and selecting `<=18` in second then it is again setting as false.
- That is due to `indexVal === index` I don't know how to handle that

**Issue**

The issue is when I am selecting age `<=18` the I am showing one input field, the I created one more `element set` and there if I am again selecting `<=18` then the Input field I have created in first component is not showing up.

[This is my code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-bird-qt6cf?file=/src/App.js)  In my code sand box I have working code, please do check

Comment: in the `onChange` handler of `select` element, you are not updating the age of that input. Here's the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leavitt-qgssg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of couple of changes you need to make in your code to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either keep track of age input by updating existing `inputHolder` or track via separate state. It would be like this:

Update onChange age

```
const onChangeAge = (e, ind) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(typeof ind, ind, typeof val);
    let inputHolderCopy = [...inputHolder];
    setindexVal(ind);
    inputHolderCopy = inputHolderCopy.map((data) => {
      if (data.id === ind + 1) {
        return { ...data, currentSelectedAge: val };
      }
      return data;
    });
    setinputHolder(inputHolderCopy);

    if (val === "<=18 ") {
      console.log("Hello");
      setageVal(true);
    } else {
      setageVal(false);
    }
  }
```

Now simply check here:

```
{onChangeAge && li.currentSelectedAge === "<=18" && (
              <div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name={`data[${index}].idCred`}
                  id="idCred"
                  placeholder="ID"
                  ref={register({ required: "ID is required" })}
                />

                <br></br>
                <label htmlFor="idCred">Name</label>
              </div>
            )}
```

here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-river-5bg7o?file=/src/App.js:2093-2527

**Note:** This is just one approach. You can do other way also. Like creating variable in `inputHolder` and keep track its value.

Comment: hey in your case I have tried it is working fine but what if i select something else, how can i remove that from the state

Comment: You mean if you choose different age input should remove?

Comment: I have updated my code. Looks like its better to track in each of its object. Check sandbox